# Can I get a list of wiki pages in GitLab?

Tags: gitlab

I'm writing an app that uses the GitLab API, and I'd like to list the pages in the wiki. I can do something like http://gitlab/username/project/wikis/home.md to get the source of an individual file, and see all pages with http://gitlab/username/project/wikis/pages, but I can't do http://gitlab/username/project/wikis/pages.md due to a 500 error.

Is there a way I can retrieve the list of files in the wiki?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there's now a GitLab Wiki API available which does everything I need:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/wikis.html

It can be used something like this:

`https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/:project_id/wikis?with_content=1&private_token=yourtokenhere`

Comment: But you would have to add your token in the wiki and everyone could have it. I don't believe this is a good practice

Comment: @MatiasBertani not necessarily. The call could be made server-side (e.g. on another server you run) and the URL constructed at run-time, or the app could require you to register your own token and use that in a locally-run app (e.g. a desktop app). Also, the token isn't actually stored on the wiki pages themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Note; if this list is to facilitate a TOC (Table of content) for navigation purpose, you now have [GitLab 13.5](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/10/22/gitlab-13-5-released/#deep-level-wiki-navigation) (October 2020), which comes with:

> ### Deep-level wiki navigation
>
> In GitLab 13.5, along with the release of group wikis, we have another huge improvement in how to view and navigate the file structure of a wiki.
>
> Currently, it’s very difficult to see where you are or understand the structure of a wiki if you have multiple folder levels. This makes it difficult to navigate, find pages, and mentally map your information.
>
> With this release, we’ve introduced wiki deep nesting in the sidebar so you can see all of your pages and navigate accordingly.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/13_5/cdybenko-wiki-deep-nesting.png -- Deep-level wiki navigation]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/wiki/#viewing-a-list-of-all-created-wiki-pages) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/17673/).

Answer (score 0):

Possibly not what you wanted (and a bit late) but if you have modified your Sidebar (i.e. _sidebar) you can make a copy of it and then delete it.

You could also add `link:pages[List all pages]`

to your home page. That might avoid, somehow, the 500 you get from `pages.md`

Answer (score 0):

The all pages route is /wikis/pages. You can add a link to your homepage, sidebar, or another page using markdown notation.

```
[View all pages](pages)
```